# new fonts not recognized in websphere server

Tags: css, web-applications, websphere

I am using custom font files in my application using @font-face css attribute. These font files are placed in project directory and referred in cas. It is working fine in local jetty server. But I am facing issue when it is deployed in websphere server. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Do you have any other static files in your project, like images, javascript files, which are served ok? You may have serving static files disabled.

Comment: Yes I do have static content served and it is working perfect ! Not sure what's the issue with fonts

Comment: Hmm, maybe css is using incorrect links for fonts. Use firebug in the browser and see what are actual links requested for the font files. Also check if it will work if you type full url for the font file in the browser.

Comment: Actual links works in both the servers. I verified with full url.. It confirms there is no issue with referencing. There should be some way to make websphere to recognize new fonts?

Comment: If the full url works on both server, then the font file is returned, so what is your actual issue?

Comment: Its not referred in the application. I don't see in the page when its rendered

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand your problem. Add short sample of page and css you are using. What do you mean you dont see the page? Are you getting 404, or page is loaded without fonts? Did you try debugging with firebug ?